# Can the 64bit ANDROID_ID be considered UUID?

Tags: android, 64-bit, collision-detection

The [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) is a 64bit ID, "*unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device.*".

While the probability that a proper UUID will be duplicated is not zero, it should be close enough to zero to be negligible. However (and I might misunderstand this), just using 64bit it doesn't take long until the likelihood of collisions begin become a real possibility.

Is this right, that after about 6 million 64bit ANDROID_IDs the likelihood of a collision is about 1 on a million? I.e. far from a negligible possibility.

[image: Table from https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/]

*Table from [Hash Collision Probabilities](https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/)*

Comment: You're not reading the chart right.  That means that adding the first 6 million values combined has a 1 in a million chance.  Adding the next value after that has a 6000000/2^64 chance.  SO vanishingly small.  Its small enough to not worry about.  The question is how many ids do you really expect to add?  If you expect to add 10s of millions, you need more bits.  If you expect 10ish million, you're good with 64

Comment: Given 6 million values, the odds of there being collision among them is 1 in a million?